# How much money do I need to show I have to visit the UK from Egpyt?

Tags: visas, uk, egyptian-citizens

How much must be in my account when I apply for a visitor visa to visit my friend in the UK? I need bank statements for the last six months. I am in Egypt.

Comment: you know the reason they ask for 6 months worth is so you can't just temporarily deposit however you much think they want to see? So are you asking us what numbers to forge onto your five-months-ago statements? Your statements are what they are; send them and see if you're approved.

Comment: We don't know the answer.  I like what @KateGregory said. I can add that there is no magic number specified anywhere. I can also add that a decent amount of refusals come from people gaming their financial standing in one way or another.